# How to implement Ajax for my wordpress site?

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm really confused.

I just desire to implement ajax in my wordpress site: clicking on each link of the menu or on each post, I'd like to show dinamycally the content in the main wrapper of the website (and at the same time I'd like to see the url changing everytime for each page or post).

I have made a research through Google and I found a multitude of tutorials or informations but each one of them is (for me) like incomplete.

Can you suggest me a good tutorial?

Or can you explain me what are the best solutions?

I read somewhere of "Ajaxify", a plugin, can it help me?

Be patient, I have always had some difficulties with ajax and in wordpress things seems to become even more complex.

Comment: They are incomplete because what you are asking is in fact more than one question. I suggest you break down the question in to parts. I.e. Part 1, how do I make an AJAX request with WP. Part 2, how do I fire the AJAX request when a button is clicked. You're much more likely to get help that way.

Comment: @DavidGard maybe you have reason, i will follow your suggestion. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I guess this tutorial can help you: http://www.designlunatic.com/2011/06/dynamically-load-wordpress-posts-with-jquery/